# How to make a list of functions in C++?

Tags: c++, list

I want to make a list of function, but the push_back doesn't work, can someone tell me why?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
    using namespace std;
    void * f(int numeraccio) {
        numeraccio++;
        cout << " " << numeraccio << " " << endl;
    };


   int main()
{

    list<void(*)(int )> l;
    l.push_back(f);
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

I get this error

```
Error C2664 'void std::list<void (__cdecl       *)(int),std::allocator<_Ty>>::push_back(const _Ty &)': impossible to convert the argument 1 from 'void *(int)' to 'void (__cdecl *&&)(int)'
```

Comment: @Ron using `std::function` is a suboptimal idea unless you need a closure

Comment: @Ron: std::function is an expensive thing. It is not designed as pointer replacement. You should understand the difference between function pointers and functors.

Comment: @Klaus Agree. Another coffee is in order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`void(*)(int )` is the type of a function pointer returning `void` not `void*`

the pointer on function that you need for f is `void*(*)(int )`

and f need a return statement

or as PaulR said, you don't want you function to return anything and your funtion pointer is good but your function declaration should be

`void f(int numeraccio)`

insteald of

```
void * f(int numeraccio)
```

Comment: He's not actually returning anything from the function though, so maybe change the function itself instead ? (`void * f(int numeraccio)` -> `void f(int numeraccio)`)

Comment: @PaulR you are probably right but i thought that is is easier to write correctly a function declaration than a function pointer type and i didn't see the missing return statement before writing the answer

Comment: Tyker you are right, I saw the error in visual studio I understood and then I come back to delete this stupid question but many answered. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can use cflow

> cflow -d 1 -b --omit-arguments --omit-symbol-names FILE_NAME.c | sed
>   's/<.*>://' > ~/LIST_FUN

Answer (score -2):

Another solution might be the use of `std::function<void(int)>`.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
    void f(int numeraccio) { // removed '*' because you are not returning anything
        numeraccio++;
        cout << " " << numeraccio << " " << endl;
    };


int main()
{

    list<std::function<void(int)> > l; // see this line 
    l.push_back(f);
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: std::function is expensive and not a replacement for function pointers. std::function is designed for functors which can also take bound parameters. So using it for pure pointers is not really helpful if time/space is a topic for the application.

Comment: the name of the header of `std::funtion` is `<functional>`. and `std::funtion` isn't need because there are noclusers

Comment: You are still tell us to use std::function. Please remove it because it is not "more clear syntax" but the wrong solution!